# Can I refer to numbers as a group?

Tags: group-theory, elementary-number-theory, elementary-set-theory

This a bit of basic question, but very delicate in its definition, at least for me.

I had a discussion with some people claiming that natural numbers is not a group.

For me any set of numbers and particularly the set of real,rational, natural, and so on are forms of groups. So I really do not understand what was the point of saying it is not a group. Can someone explain the issue (it might be a language issue but I think it is more fundamental than that even.)?

Because one can claim that the more fundamental representation of number is by group and not by counting. But I find difficult to understand the sentence " The natural numbers are not a group". So if anyone is an expert on this field or knows what this person meant I will be glad for a clear explanation. Someone of us surly be wrong because the fundamental representation of the natural numbers must be valid as a group or not.

So if someone can shed some light on the subject I would be grateful.

Comment: Firstly, you cannot define a group without defining the group law that acts upon the members of the specified set. Moreover, say you chose one, how would you satisfy the inverse axiom, i.e. how would you satisfy the condition: $$\forall a \in \mathbb{N},\exists b \in \mathbb{N} : a \cdot b = b \cdot a = e$$ Where $e$ is the identity element?

Comment: So the real numbers is also not a group because of zero? Or, zero can be equal to e?

Comment: Real numbers can form a group, for instance under the group $(\mathbb{R},+)$, where $e = 0$; but $(\mathbb{R},*)$ for instance is not a group.

Comment: Is the confusion perhaps that when you say "group", you just mean a collection of (related) things, while when most mathematicians say "group", they mean "a set, together with a binary operation which satisfies the following axioms..."?

Comment: Yes I think I meant a collection in that aspect. Maybe in hebrew it is the same word. A set also have this axiom? Is the natural numbers are a set??

Comment: Yes, most mathematicians would call the natural numbers a set. (Though there are [very few] mathematics who reject the notion of infinite sets. That position is called finitism, I believe) We have to be careful about what we call a set, however, because of considerations like Russel's Paradox. It generally seems to be accepted that accepting the natural numbers as a set probably won't lead to any trouble.

Comment: So what is the most basic and accepted definition of all the numbers that are natural?

Comment: @sivi As far as I gathered, it is indeed the same word in Hebrew. And it's a common mistake for speakers of Hebrew to say/write group when they mean set, there are plenty of examples (mostly corrected meanwhile) on the site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The natural numbers are not a group. One of the requirements of a group is that every element possesses an inverse. For the natural numbers, this requirement fails under the operation of addition as well as multiplication. The integers are a group under addition however, but not multiplication.

Comment: Are you sure about this?

Comment: As noted in the comments on the question, "group" is a technical word in Mathematics, and it is as 270500 says. The natural numbers form a "set", but not a group.

Comment: Yes I am absolutely sure.